# How To Incorporate AWS Glue Job Parameters Into SQL Query in Glue Visual Editor?

Tags: parameters, aws-glue

I am creating an AWS Glue job using the Glue Visual Editor.  The Glue job uses the SQL Query node to run a SQL query on an S3 source, including filtering on a start date and end date.  How would I set that date range using an input parameter?

Here is the Glue job.  It's currently running fine, with the start date and end date hardcoded.

[Glue job showing SQL query with hardcoded start and end date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxjuY.png)

Here are the input parameters I created for the job.

[Glue job input parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NswRk.png)

How would I access the parameters in the job, using the visual editor, and incorporate them into my SQL query?  Is this possible?

I've searched online for a way to access the parameters in the Glue visual interface, and searched the Glue menu for an input widget that would expose the parameters.  No luck so far.

Thank you!

Comment: Update: I ended up using a workaround for this.  Instead of using the Glue job parameters, I created an S3 bucket to store job parameters in csv format.  I use the S3 widget in the Glue visual editor to access the csv file with the job parameters, then treat it as a table and join to the necessary data.